# Having trouble if else statement

Tags: php

For some reason its not getting to the part of line 174 and I don't know why. Any suggestions what the solution could or might be.

http://pastebin.com/vFZwmJuc

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` the principal variables, as `$minutes`?

Comment: please provide a smaller but working example of your problem. This is way too much, badly indented and untestable. Try to bring it down to an example you could show here. Then, tells us what you think should happen in that if, and what does happen, and why this surprises you.

Comment: There's not enough context here to answer. Your question is why doesn't your code fork into an else block - does it fork into the if block?

Comment: Are you sure that your display_errors is on? and you are not getting an invisible error.

Answer (score 0):

`$minutes` might never be less than 10?

`echo` `$minutes` on line 173 to check

Answer (score 0):

Why .. why so many useless calculations (lines 159-163)? From what I see you need to find out the difference in minutes only. If so -- replace the above mentioned lines by this:

```
$minutes = floor($diff / 60);
```

**Test Examples:**

```
$currTime = '2011-06-12 10:27:00';
$lockTime = '2011-06-12 10:26:05';

$diff = abs(strtotime($currTime) - strtotime($lockTime));
$minutes = floor($diff / 60);
echo $minutes, "\n";

$currTime = '2011-06-12 10:27:00';
$lockTime = '2011-06-12 09:26:05';

$diff = abs(strtotime($currTime) - strtotime($lockTime));
$minutes = floor($diff / 60);
echo $minutes, "\n";
```

**Test Results:**

```
0
60
```

**EDIT:** Also, on line 174 -- your text is `Your account is currently locked. You must wait ' .$chancesLeft.' minutes before you can log in again!`. The message tells about **minutes** but **$chancesLeft** is used.